# Remove actual visible element from object array

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
struct FilesToDownload {
    var fileInternetUrl: String?
    var fileName: String?
    var savedURL: String?
    var productImageUrl: URL?
    var fileSize: Int
}


var filesToDownload = [FilesToDownload]()


func startDownloadFiles(filesArray: [FilesToDownload], filesType: Int){
        for files in filesArray{
            print("- files.fileName")
            // here remove element files.fileName from array  filesToDownload
        }
    }
```

How can I remove the currently displayed element files.fileName from the startDownloadFiles array?

Comment: Use inout parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple you have to find the index of object in `filesToDownload` array which matches `files.fileName` and remove element form that index

```
 if let index = filesToDownload.index(where: {$0.fileName.lowercased() == files.fileName.lowercased() }) {
     filesToDownload.remove(at:index)     
  }
```

Comment: OK, if I wanted to delete one file without a for loop knowing the file name?